# Does where clause improve performance if no user defined indexes are present?

Tags: sql

Does simply adding a `WHERE` clause improve the performance of a `SELECT` statement, even if I have not defined any indexes?

For example is :

```
SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Grade='A';
```

faster than

```
SELECT * FROM Students;
```

even with no index on column "Grade"?

Answer (score 1):

The performance of a SQL query depends on many factors.  One of those factors is the amount of data being returned.  Another is the overhead of evaluating expressions

So, does your `where` clause result in better performance in this simple query?  That depends on two competing factors:

- How expensive does the condition cost?  A comparison to a constant is pretty basic, but there is *some* overhead.
- How many rows are being returned?

Note:  Parsing the `where` clause probably also requires a microsecond or two of additional overhead during the compilation phase.  Normally, the compilation phase is not considered when asking about performance, because actually processing the data usually dwarfs that time.

As an example, if all students have `Grade = 'A'`, then the `where` clause will *decrease* the performance of the query, because the comparison adds overhead to every row.

On the other hand, if no students have `Grade = 'A'` and there are many rows in the table, then the performance is probably *better*.  Returning no rows is typically faster than returning many rows.

Also note that there are other factors as well that affect performance -- such as the use of partitions and algorithmic choices in more complex queries.